# Webpage Download Time and export to CSV via batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl, export-to-csv

I am trying to set up a batch file to get webpage download time using curl command and export to `CSV` or text file.

I am using the following curl command:

```
curl http ://myurl.com -w %{time_total}\n -o NUL -s
```

The command above works when using it in `cmd` and will provide a response `ex - 0.188000`.

However, when I am using the command via a batch file and try to export using the following, it does not work. Instead of `.1888000`, I get `{time_total}`.

```
@echo on
ECHO.
totaltimeresponse
ECHO.
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\software\curl
ECHO.
curl http ://myurl.com -w %{time_total}\n -o NUL -s >> total-time.txt
ECHO.
```

This is my first time working with `curl` and batch files, so I am not sure what is happening. I have researched and researched, but I still don't know what wrong I have made.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows machine to test, but try this --should work.

```
@echo on
ECHO.
totaltimeresponse
ECHO.
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\software\curl
ECHO.
curl http ://myurl.com -w %%{time_total}\n -o NUL -s >> total-time.txt
ECHO.
```

Comment: Tested with .csv and .txt and this works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help